# DC.js - trigger elastic resize when criteria are met

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I would like to trigger elastic resizing on outliers in certain graphs when the largest values are removed. Here's what I have so far:

```
dmsn = ndx.dimension(...)
groupTotal = dmsn.group().reduceSum(...)

row
  .width(100)
  .height(100)
  .dimension(dmsn)
  .group(groupTotal)

document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
  setTimeout(function(e){
    newTop = groupTotal.top(1)[0].value;
    ratio = newTop / origTop;
    if(ratio < .1){
        row.elasticX(true);
        dc.redrawAll('groupTotal');
    } else {
        row.elasticX(false);
        dc.redrawAll('groupTotal');
    }
  },1);
}, true);
```

The function checks to see whether the new highest value is sufficiently small that a readjustment is useful.

The timeout ensures that the ratio is correctly calculated after the filters are applied. However, this also means that the opportunity to apply the new elasticity has passed. Unfortunately the redrawAll doesn't appear to work here.

Any advice on fixing this implementation or achieving this some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to achieve this, for anyone curious. This results in conditional scaling of axes when the largest current bar is too small (or large) to be valuable.

```
var currentMax = 0,
    ratio,
    chartMax = groupData.top(1)[0].value; // initialize with largest value

row
  .on('postRedraw', function(chart){
    currentMax = groupData.top(1)[0].value; // after redraw, capture largest val
    ratio = currentMax/chartMax;
    if(ratio < .1 || ratio > 1){ // check if bars are too small or too large
        row.elasticX(true);
        chartMax = currentMax; // always be sure to reset the chartMax
        dc.redrawAll();
    } else {
        row.elasticX(false);
        chartMax = currentMax;
    }
  });
```